# iOS Swift Pin PEM Certificate to Run REST POST Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

I've been trying to use Alamofire to pin a PEM certificate using these methods:

- [SSL pinning in iOS - Swift edition](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/ssl-pinning-revisited)
- [Adding certificate pinning to your iOS app with Alamofire](https://www.vincentrenais.com/posts/adding-certificate-pinning-to-your-ios-app)

I've also tried using `AFNetworking`:

```
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:certificatePath];
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certificateData);
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge_transfer NSData *)SecCertificateCopyData(cert), nil];
[securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:arr];
```

Most of the time I will get -999 and -1012 errors. When running a curl command, it works as it should. However, it does not seem to work when converting the PEM certificate to a DER format.

Comment: Hi could you please give me some more details to understand. The code is in objective c, do you want to have it in swift or objective c.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223291/ios-certificate-pinning-with-swift-and-nsurlsession/34223292